# ubuntu16.04でsudo apt-get -f install コマンドが実行できません

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

`sudo apt-get -f install` とコマンドを端末で入力したのですが

```
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています                
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
依存関係を解決しています ... 完了
以下のパッケージが自動でインストールされましたが、もう必要とされていません:
linux-headers-4.4.0-59 linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62
linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-63
linux-headers-4.4.0-63-generic linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-63-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-63-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-59-generic
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-63-generic
これを削除するには 'sudo apt autoremove' を利用してください。
以下の追加パッケージがインストールされます:
python-appindicator
以下のパッケージはアップグレードされます:
python-appindicator
アップグレード: 1 個、新規インストール: 0 個、削除: 0 個、保留: 308 個。
3 個のパッケージが完全にインストールまたは削除されていません。
7,740 B のアーカイブを取得する必要があります。
この操作後に 36.9 kB のディスク容量が解放されます。
続行しますか? [Y/n] Y
取得:1 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 python-appindicator amd64 12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1 [7,740 B]
7,740 B を 0秒 で取得しました (75.0 kB/s)       
(データベースを読み込んでいます ... 現在 325947 個のファイルとディレクトリがインストールされています。)
.../python-appindicator_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb を展開する準備をしています ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-appindicator.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-appindicator.prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: 警告: サブプロセス 古い pre-removal スクリプト はエラー終了ステータス 127 を返しました
dpkg: 代わりに新規パッケージからスクリプトを実行してみます ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: pyclean: not found
dpkg: アーカイブ /var/cache/apt/archives/python-appindicator_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb の処理中にエラーが発生しました (--unpack):
サブプロセス 新しい pre-removal スクリプト はエラー終了ステータス 127 を返しました
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-appindicator.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-appindicator.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: クリーンアップ中にエラーが発生しました:
サブプロセス インストール済みの post-installation スクリプト はエラー終了ステータス 127 を返しました
処理中にエラーが発生しました:
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-appindicator_12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

とエラーをはいて実行することができません。
環境はUbuntu 16.04です。
これは何が原因なのでしょうか？教えてくださると助かります。

sudo apt-get updateのログは以下のようになっています。

```
ヒット:1 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
無視:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                          
取得:3 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]          
取得:4 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]        
ヒット:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release                          
取得:6 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [572 kB]
取得:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]           
取得:8 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [553 kB] 
取得:10 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [299 kB]
取得:11 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [195 kB]
取得:12 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [492 kB]
取得:13 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [473 kB]
取得:14 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [163 kB]
取得:15 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [203 kB]
取得:16 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,516 B]
取得:17 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
取得:18 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [4,672 B]
ヒット:19 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
ヒット:20 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial InRelease
取得:21 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [54.6 kB]
取得:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [50.7 kB]
取得:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [35.8 kB]
取得:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [52.2 kB]
3,460 kB を 1秒 で取得しました (1,941 kB/s)                             
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
```

Comment: エラーメッセージに `pyclean: not found` や `pycompile: not found` などがありますので、`python-minimal` パッケージがインストールされていないのではないでしょうか。

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-minimalを実行したところ
""パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています                
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
python-minimal はすでに最新バージョン (2.7.11-1) です。
python-minimal は手動でインストールしたと設定されました。
以下の問題を解決するために 'apt-get -f install' を実行する必要があるかもしれません:
以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 python-appindicator : 依存: libappindicator1 (= 12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1) しかし、12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1 はインストールされようとしています
E: 未解決の依存関係です。'apt-get -f install' を実行してみてください (または解法を明示してください)。"" と出ました。 python-minimalが原因ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: @user22627 `sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-minimal` で再インストールしても改善しませんか？

Comment: sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-minimal
""パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています                
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
以下の問題を解決するために 'apt-get -f install' を実行する必要があるかもしれません:
以下のパッケージには満たせない依存関係があります:
 python-appindicator : 依存: libappindicator1 (= 12.10.1+15.04.20141110-0ubuntu1) しかし、12.10.1+16.04.20170215-0ubuntu1 はインストールされようとしています
E: 未解決の依存関係です。'apt-get -f install' を実行してみてください (または解法を明示してください)。""
と表示されます。sudo apt-get -f install もエラーが出て実行できません。

Comment: @user22627 ログの中に「保留: 308個」とあるのが気になるのですが、もしかして Ubuntu をアップグレードなさいましたか？　もしかすると（少し古いですが）Ubuntu日本語フォーラムの[こちらのスレッド](https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=9781)に書いてあることと状況が似ているかもしれません。もしアップグレードなさったのでしたら、`sudo apt-get update` のログを質問本文にコピペして下さいませんか？ (自分の質問には「編集」から自由に追記できます)

Comment: アップグレードは行っていないのですが、一応ログは本文に載せておきます

Answer (score -1):

pythonパッケージは関係ありません。/bootが一杯になっているのでインストールできないだけですね。
`sudo apt autoremove`すればうまくいくはずです。

Comment: 後学のために教えて頂きたいのですが、どのあたりからそう判断されたのでしょうか？

Comment: 同じ現象が起こるのでそう判断しただけです。

Comment: 「同じ現象」とはどのくらい同じことなのですか？　たとえば `pyclean: not found` といったエラーが出ていらっしゃるのでしょうか。